# Implement password hashing for mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, hash, passwords

This is for a database linked to the signup form on a website. All the answers on here simply mention that using hashing is what you should do, no one explains how to implement it. I already have the database working, I just need to implement password hashing.

I've got the input form on the website. I would think that you simply run the password variable that the form spits out through the hashing algorithm and pass it on to the database but that would mean any user could easily see the hashing algorithm with "view page source". What is the general practice with this. Is there a way to store the algorithm somewhere else? Does it not matter if the user can see it or not?

Edit: I am planning on using SHA256 if that matters.

Comment: Use a server language for password hashing

Comment: For instance, in PHP you use the `password_hash()` function.

Comment: Basically all hashing algorithms used are public and well known. Their strength doesn’t depend on them being secret, quite the opposite. But usually the hashing isn’t done on the web page, there’s some server side mechanism that handles it. Web pages don’t connect to databases directly.

Comment: Use a password hash algorithm on the server side, neither the client nor the database should do the hashing. Recommended algorithms are BCrypt, SCrypt, Argon2 and PBKDF2. Do not use SHA-* for passwords, because such algorithms are way too fast and can be brute-forced too easily.

Comment: is your website 100% javascript? if not, what's the language used for the backend? Javascript is not the better language for crypto, but there are lot of library for java, PHP and others